# Using Event Target to return specific data in the console

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to use an event listener to return specific data from the console made from an API call and apply it to a variable to make another API call.

The calls are made through functions that return the data in JSON format.

The console data is as follows:

```
href: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7f0vVL3xi4i78Rv5Ptn2s1"
id: "7f0vVL3xi4i78Rv5Ptn2s1"
```

I'm trying to only access the id portion to use it in a new API call. I have an event listener that I would like to use which receives the id on click.

```
DOMInputs.tracks.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        const trackId = e.target.id;
}
```

However, the variable trackId contains the href instead of the id. Resulting in:

```
app.js:74 GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/7f0vVL3xi4i78Rv5Ptn2s1 404
```

Where the second link is contained in ${trackId} Is there a work around or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to know the same thing. I simply used `const trackEndPoint = e.target.id.replace('https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/', '');`